# How they avoid problems with concept-based overloading without explicit models (a.k.a. concept maps)

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

As it is pointed in a number of talks and papers by Andrew Sutton, Concepts Lite proposal does have concept-based overloading feature and at the same time does not have a notion of concept map, that is template arguments are checked against concepts entirely by a compiler. Given this it is not clear how would they resolve a problem described in 2005 paper by Siek and Gregor, “[Explicit model definitions are necessary](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1798.html)”. In short the problem could be stated with the following quotation from the paper.

> So, there are certain input iterator types (such as istream_iterator) that would be misclassified as forward iterators. What is the danger in this? Some algorithms dispatch based on Input_iterator vs. Forward_iterator.

(There are more examples besides iterators though.)

Yes, I'm aware of that above mentioned paper considered C++0x concepts, but the problem seems to be “generic” over concepts proposals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proposal in [n3351 *A Concept Design for the STL*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3351.pdf) is to continue to use iterator category tags:

```
concept InputIterator<WeakInputIterator I> =
    EqualityComparable<I> &&
    Derived<IteratorCategory<I>, input_iterator_tag>;
```

In the syntax expected for inclusion into the standard per [n4377 *C++ Extensions for Concepts*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4377.pdf):

```
template<typename I>
concept bool InputIterator =
    WeakInputIterator<I>() && EqualityComparable<I>() &&
    Derived<IteratorCategory<I>, input_iterator_tag>();
```

From the former paper:

> While C++11 makes it
>   possible to evaluate all static requirements [...] we still need to differentiate
>   some concepts based on their semantic requirements. The iterator category solves that problem
>   for us.

In general, one can express semantic requirements by checking a type predicate (e.g. a nested type or constant, or a type function) that exists solely for the purpose of asserting a runtime semantic.

Comment: @Columbo I've attempted to rewrite it in n4377 syntax; please check check whether I've got it right (I don't have access to a Concepts-enabled compiler right now).

Comment: The syntax you had was correct, but a bit odd in that there's no need for a requires-expression if you don't need to refer to its parameters. I've simplified it.

Comment: Sorry, is it possible to say `template<WeakInputIterator I> concept bool InputIterator = EqualityComparable<I>() && ...`?

Comment: @ArtemPelenitsyn that doesn't appear to be allowed; n4377 has `template<C T>
concept bool V3 = true; // error: constrained template declared as a concept`

Comment: @ecatmur great, thank you. Did they drop this abbreviated syntax only for concept decls or at all (for usual templates)?

Comment: @ArtemPelenitsyn constrained type specifiers and constrained parameters are still in: `void f(C c); template<C T> struct s;`

Comment: @ArtemPelenitsyn They dropped the abbreviated syntax from concept definitions. Since the point of the abbreviated syntax is to apply constraints to the template being declared, and concept templates cannot be constrained, it's inconsistent.

Comment: "I don't have access to a Concepts-enabled compiler right now." Yes, you do. [The concepts branch of GCC has been merged to trunk, so Wandbox is a Concepts-enabled compiler with -std=gnu++1z."](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/2DkixUSp9FhI5ZM3)